# How to handle the html and jsp pages in spring mvc from the same URI pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

we usually use different URI for HTML and JSP
like

```
"/static/help" for mapping HTML pages
"/jsp/deposit" for mapping jsp pages
```

How can i map both HTML and JSP from same URI
like

```
"/help" should map to "help.html"
"/deposit" should map to "deposit.jsp"
```

Suppose i have below URI(without extension) which needs to be mapped to given location

and also i don't want to put extensions like .html or .jsp in return value of controller's view name since it is not the best practice.

How can i achieve it?

dispatcher servlet url mapping- "/"

```
Request         Controller's           Physical 
URI              logical                File
                view name               location
------          ----------             ------------
"/"              "home"                 WEB-INF/common/home.html
"/help"          "help"                 WEB-INF/common/help.html
"/deposit"       "deposit"              WEB-INF/app/deposit.jsp
"/withdraw"      "withdraw"             WEB-INF/app/withdraw.jsp
```

Comment: Anything that is placed inside WEB-INF is "processed" by servlet container. It's better to put static files (I assume that your html files are static) outside of WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Yep, mistake in copy and paste, they are already outside btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Keep your suffix empty

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/yourDirectory/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=""/>
</bean>
```

And the in the controller

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/deposit")
public String deposit() {
    return "deposit.jsp";
}
```

Comment: is it work? do you mean return "app/deposit.jsp"; ?

Comment: @Amir yes add subfolders in the return internal to directory mentioned in prefix

Answer (score 0):

Step1
Create A Class that extends org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView

Step2
Override the method checkResource
The final Class will be like this:

```
package com.hanz.view;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HtmlResourceView extends InternalResourceView {
    @Override
    public boolean checkResource(Locale locale) {
        File file = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + getUrl());
        return file.exists();
    }
}
```

Step3 Make the config right
Open the spring-mvc.xml,add this class's bean config,like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolverHtml" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="com.seeyon.wxapps.base.utils.view.HtmlResourceView"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="order" value="3"/>
    </bean>
```